# Disable/Enable ReorderList Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, asp.net-3.5

Hopefully this is a simple question to answer

I have a ReorderList control on a page within an UpdatePanel and all I want to do is disable it until the user clicks on an Edit button and disable it again once the user clicks on a Save/Cancel buttons.

I've tried toggling the Enabled property but that doesn't work. Changing the AllowReorder disables the control but it cannot be re-enabled by changing AllowReorder back to true.

There must be a way of doing this - either I'm going mad or suffering from post-Christmas blues!!

Comment: Have you tried using jQuery.

Comment: I can probably use JQuery to block the ReorderList but it should be unnecessary with a server control

Answer (score 0):

> Changing the AllowReorder disables the control but it cannot be
>   re-enabled by changing AllowReorder back to true.

Actually, it should. If you use UpdatePanel controls or register buttons as async postback controls, check carefully, is ReorderList control updated on partial postback.

Also, you can disable reordering with javascript below:

```
var dragDropWatcher = $find("<%= ReorderList1.UniqueID %>_dItemEx");
var originalCanDrop = dragDropWatcher.canDrop;

//to disable reorder
dragDropWatcher.canDrop = function(){ return false; };

//to enable reorder
dragDropWatcher.canDrop = originalCanDrop;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Yuriy but setting AllowReorder just doesn't work. However, I have found a workaorund that avoids having to use JQuery on the client side. I simply use a Repeater control to emulate the ReorderList in view mode and toggle the visibility of Repeater/ReorderList during the click events.